# Fill the Declaer object in sql?

Tags: sql-server, function

I have question maybe it s simple somehow but there is my real problem.
I have scalar value function in SQL that take one parameter. I have query that I use this function in my select query. The problem is that the input parameter is one my table column.
How can I fill the declare object in my query?

```
declare @duedate varchar (10)  

SELECT FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate,dbo.GTOP(SubscribedDate) as pers FROM ClubProfile CP 
  WHERE CP.CardNumber IS NOT NULL
  AND IsExpired =0
  group by cp.SubscribedDate,FirstName,LastName
  set @duedate = (select SubscribedDate from ClubProfile)
```

Comment: i did it but it does not work

Comment: Your query is not exactly clear. As posted you are passing NULL to dbo.GTOP. Also, scalar functions (especially in a column list) are a recipe for horrible performance. You would be far better off replacing that scalar function with something that will offer much better performance.

Comment: my column dont have any null value

Comment: Right but you are passing the duedate variable which was defined but the value is NULL so that is what is being passed to your scalar function. As posted it is like this. dbo.GTOP(NULL)

Comment: thank you from your attention but i column that is not null and i pass this column into my function

Comment: You don't pass the column, you are passing @duedate which is a variable in t-sql. You probably should be passing the column but you aren't in the code you posted.

Comment: The other issue is do you have more than 1 row in ClubProfile? If so, what would expect the variable to have?

Comment: yes i have 2000 record on my table . this function convert gregorian to persian calender  . when i put the exat time like '2015-01-06 13:13:49.857' it work for me but when  i want use column does not work

Comment: So you're projecting (selecting) every value of SubscribeDate as evaluated by the GTOP function, and then, separately, you're trying to assign a value to dueDate (NOT modified by GTOP). What value, of the possible ~2000 SubscribeDates do you want to be assigned to the dueDate variable? Because right now it's effectively random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FirstName,LastName,SubscribedDate,dbo.GTOP(SubscribedDate) as pers
FROM ClubProfile CP 
WHERE CP.CardNumber IS NOT NULL
AND IsExpired =0
```

Comment: do you really need a group by? I updated mine to remove it an add a DISTINCT which is what I think you are trying to do. You should be more clear on what you are seeing.

Comment: sorry man . i not native . i tried you code but i have some error!!

Comment: @user3532929 "I have some error!", can you be more specific?

Comment: Try my code that was updated above, and if it's not producing what you expect. Explain it here as a comment please. Thanks!